# Removing field completely inside nested array of mongodb docs

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is a bunch of sample docs with same structure of data i have in mongodb.

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "conf" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "HOUSE",
            "criteria" : [ 
                {
                    "key" : "AST",
                    "value" : [ 
                        "0", 
                        "1" 
                        ]
                }, 
                {
                    "key" : "CD",
                    "value" : [ 
                        "!", 
                        "@", 
                        "#"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        } 
    ]
}
```

In the above doc. I wanted to remove the below block in all docs at once.

{
"key" : "CD",
"value" : [
"!",
"@",
"#"
]
}
I tried it and its removing the content inside but leaving the {} which should also be removed.

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "conf" : [ 
        {
            "Name" : "HOUSE",
            "criteria" : [ 
                {
                    "key" : "AST",
                    "value" : [ 
                        "0", 
                        "1" 
                        ]
                }, 
                {}
            ]
        } 
    ]
}
```

Can someone help on this?

Note: Value field does not have the same values(!,                        @,#) in all docs. Its different in each docs.

Comment: see this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sv5pUoGJb5f).

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Comment: Turivishal, It works. Thanks a lot